# C: Why are my functions returning 0 values?

Tags: c

I've got a short program that's supposed to pass an array of float values to three different functions to return the sum, average, and smallest value.  I can't figure out why the functions are returning 0 values (or am I passing the array incorrectly?)

I'm sure I've missed something simple and fundamental, but have been staring at this too long and really can't see what's wrong.

Appreciate any input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 5


float array_sum (float arr[]);
float array_avg (float arr[]);
float array_min (float arr[]);

int main ()
{
    float array_nums[NUM] = {1.23, 4.56, 7.89, 10.1, 2.34};
    float arr_sum;
    float arr_avg;
    float arr_min;

    arr_sum = array_sum(array_nums);
    arr_avg = array_avg(array_nums);
    arr_min = array_min(array_nums);

    printf("\nThe sum of the elements in the array is %f.\n"), arr_sum;
    printf("The average of the elements in the array is %f.\n"), arr_avg;
    printf("The smallest value in the array is %f.\n\n"), arr_min;

return (0);
}

float array_sum (float arr[])
{
    float sum = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

return (sum);
}

float array_avg (float arr[])
{

    int i;
    float avg;
    float sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    avg = sum/NUM;

return (avg);
}

float array_min (float arr[])
{
    int i;
    float min = arr[0];

    for (i=0; i < NUM; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }

return (min);
}
```

Comment: Use a decent compiler like gcc -Wall and it will tell you that your printfs lack sufficient arguments for their formats. And I think it will also tell you that you're calculating expressions with no effect.

Answer (score 5):

Your `printf`s have the arguments outside of the function:

```
printf("\nThe sum of the elements in the array is %f.\n"), arr_sum;
                                                        ^ end of arguments
```

should be

```
printf("\nThe sum of the elements in the array is %f.\n", arr_sum);
```

Comment: D'oh.  Simple and fundamental indeed.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 5):

As others pointed out, your `printf` statements are wrong; you placed the argument outside the brackets (inadvertently, you used the **comma operator**, which evaluates the thing on the left of the comma, then the right of the comma, and produces this last result).

If you use the `-Wall` compiler flag, your compiler will normally warn you (saying e.g. "missing format argument for `%f`"). In general, you should turn on most warnings when using C, as they often point out bugs and errors in your programs that can otherwise be hard to catch.

Answer (score 3):

Your printf statements are incorrect. This is the right way to do it:

```
printf("\nThe sum of the elements in the array is %f.\n", arr_sum);
printf("The average of the elements in the array is %f.\n", arr_avg);
printf("The smallest value in the array is %f.\n\n", arr_min);
```

You can also limit the decimal places to be displayed by doing this:

```
printf("\nThe sum of the elements in the array is %0.2f.\n", arr_sum); //this will display 2 decimal places
```

Answer (score 3):

At a quick glance, it' s a parenthesis issue:

```
printf("\nThe sum of the elements in the array is %f.\n"), arr_sum;
```

Should be:

```
printf("\nThe sum of the elements in the array is %f.\n", arr_sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a small mistake. corrected code is here,

```
printf("\nThe sum of the elements in the array is %f.\n", arr_sum);
    printf("The average of the elements in the array is %f.\n",arr_avg) ;
    printf("The smallest value in the array is %f.\n\n", arr_min);
```